# How to hide actions in floatingButton

Tags: flutter

I am trying to have a FloatingButton with multiple options and each option triggers an action. I achieve that so far, and also an animated transition when pressed. What I need is to achieve that when the Button is not pressed, only one icon is showing.

This is the code so far:

```
class _FloatingButtonMultipleOptionState extends State<FloatingButtonMultipleOption> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isOpened = false;
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<Color> _buttonColor;
  Animation<double> _animateIcon;
  Animation<double> _translateButton;
  Curve _curve = Curves.easeOut;
 double _fabHeight = 56.0;

  @override
  initState() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500))
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    _animateIcon = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_animationController);
    _buttonColor = ColorTween(
      begin: TheBaseColors.lightBlue,
      end: TheBaseColors.lightRed,
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Interval(
        0.00,
        1.00,
        curve: Curves.linear,
      ),
    ));
    _translateButton = Tween<double>(
      begin: _fabHeight,
      end: -14.0,
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _animationController,
      curve: Interval(
        0.0,
        0.75,
        curve: _curve,
      ),
    ));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  animate() {
    if (!isOpened) {
      _animationController.forward();
    } else {
      _animationController.reverse();
    }
    isOpened = !isOpened;
  }

  Widget post() {
    return FloatingActionButton.extended(
      heroTag: null,
      onPressed: (){
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreatePost()));

      },
      tooltip: 'Post',
      label: Row(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('Send a Post'),
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.message,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget activity() {
    return FloatingActionButton.extended(
        heroTag: null,
        onPressed: (){
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateActivity()));

        },
        tooltip: 'Activiy',
        label: Row(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text('Create activity'),
            ),
            Icon(Icons.event),
          ],
        ),
      );
  }

  Widget close() {
    return  FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: _buttonColor.value,
        onPressed: animate,
        tooltip: 'Close',
        child: AnimatedIcon(
          icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
          progress: _animateIcon,
        ),
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
            0.0,
            _translateButton.value * 3.0,
            0.0,
          ),
          child: post(),
        ),
        Transform(
          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
            0.0,
            _translateButton.value * 2.0,
            0.0,
          ),
          child: activity(),
        ),
        close(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

In the photo attached you can see how when the button is not pressed, the user can see the option 'Create activity' and this should only be seen when the button is pressed.
[image]

Comment: There is no photo attached.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a boolean "isButtonPressed" that changes state every time you press the FloatingActionButton, and then wrap the other buttons into the Visibility widget like this

```
 Visibility(
  visible: isButtonPressed,
  child: activity(),
 )
```

This will make your floatingActionButton "Create activity" visible when the button is pressed, and hide it when the button is pressed a second time.

Comment: Hi, can you be more specific please? I wrapped my floating button as you said but it still not working

Comment: The Visibility widget allows its child to be visible only when the boolean value on the "visible:" argument is set to true. This means if you set it to false by default, and then only set it to true when the first floatingActionButton is pressed, the activity widget will only appear when you click the floating action button. Please share some code of what you tried if you're not able to do it so I can try to help you more.